# How to use the current user as a method argument in QuerySet property

Tags: django

- I have Events
- A user can subscribe to an Event
- In views I have a list of Events
- In the list template I would like have something like event.allready_subscribed available. So that the current user can see that he/she has already subscribed.

I can't do this in a model method, because I don't have the request.user available.

Comment: Why would annotate be overdone? Seems appropriate to me

Comment: You can check `{% if request.user in some_event.subscribers %}` (given `subscribers` is the reverse name of the relation), but annotation is better since it will either result in the "*N+1*-problem", or in prefetching a lot of useless data.

Comment: I think however it is advisable to share the (relevant parts of the) models.

Comment: You can furthermore implement a method in the models with a parameter, and then thus perform the annotation *with* that parameter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't seem to be able to use a model method in annotate. Only actual DB fields. And if I was able to do it, wouldn't it fire a lot of extra queries?

I solved it now this way? What do you and @DanielRoseman think?

`my_events = EventRegistration.objects.filter( user=request.user.id ).values_list('event_id', flat=True)
events = Event.objects.all().annotate( allready_registered=models.Case(models.When(pk__in=my_events, then=models.Value(True)), default=models.Value(False), output_field=models.BooleanField()))`

Comment: If there are 100 events, it will result in 101 queries, if there are 1000 events, it will yield 1001 queries, that is the trouble with the *N+1* problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, and my solution now is only 2 queries. So that seems a good approach ...  or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments.

```
my_events = EventRegistration.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).values_list('event_id', flat=True)

events = Event.objects.all().annotate(allready_registered=models.Case(models.When(pk__in=my_events, then=models.Value(True)), default=models.Value(False), output_field=models.BooleanField()))
```